# Fail2ban bans not working

Tags: ubuntu, fail2ban

What exactly does a ban do? I know this kinda absurd to ask, but still. I know it ban login attempts. But does it prevent banned IPs from attempting succesful logins?

I banned a test ip (both manually and porpusly failing), yet i can still login when using proper user and keys. And as far as i know the jail is enabled.

Also, (bonus question) is having max attempts on zero an overkill?

I ask because i use a key and known port (not 22) to login, so either my login is corrupt or i login succesfully. So i dont expect to be attempting unsuccesfully.

Comment: max attempt of 0 is usually: disable. If someone cannot even try once, then try infinite? Could be your issue. That said, where are you setting things up?

Comment: @LPChip I'll set it to 1 max. Also, what do you mean by where?

Comment: Never mind, I missed the ubuntu tag and am not familiar enough with it to know about fail2ban and jail etc.

Answer (score 0):

> What exactly does a ban do?

It completely depends on what actions you have enabled in the jail's configuration. The default, however, is to block the IP address through your system firewall (iptables or nft).

With iptables, run `iptables-save` – this should show you that the main input chain has a jump to the "f2b-sshd" chain, which then has either a basic IP address block or an ipset-based block. (If it's empty, fail2ban did not take any action yet. On the other hand, if you do find a rule, make sure it is blocking the correct TCP port!)

On systems using nft run `nft list ruleset` and look for similar rules.

> But does it prevent banned IPs from attempting succesful logins?

Yes. You don't know whether a login is successful until after it has been attempted.

> Also, (bonus question) is having max attempts on zero an overkill?

Yes. (Assuming you mean zero *failed* attempts, at least.) It doesn't protect you from random bruteforce botnets any better than 3–5 attempts, and it doesn't protect you from dedicated attackers who can easily switch to a new IP address for their next try.

Sooner or later, you *will* manage to lock yourself out by accidentally using the wrong key (e.g. mixing up personal and work keys), or connecting from a system which has a different local username (and forgetting to specify the right one in ssh command), or mistyping the SSH key's passphrase.

Comment: Super answer, thanks!!! On regards of my port, I do have a different port set rather than 22.
And on `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` under `#Actions`
`# Ports to be banned`
`# Usually should be overridden in a particular jail`
`port = 0:65535`  Anyways, if it is the ports i don’t know why i can still succesfully login when banned. And i checked with `iptables -S` to rectify the ban is also there